# Android: How to get two ImageView(s) overlayed with transparency

Tags: imageview, transparency

I have two ImageView(s) (let's name them, A and B) that are perfectly overlayed in the xml layout.

B has transparent background.

In my activity I firstly display on A a Bitmap with opaque colours.

Then, I display on B a transparent Bitmap (afterwards, it is planned to draw something on it trhough a canvas).

As a result of this, I get a totally black view.

I would like to be able to see the first Bitmap that I displayed on A.

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning on drawing something over it via a canvas, i would suggest you write a custom view class.

I have previously created an app in which i had a background-image, and on top of that the user was able to draw. I did this by building up a custom view class that extended [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html).